# Explain jump table construct in RISC-V assembly

Tags: assembly, riscv, jump-table

In some disassembly I see `jal ra sym.imp.strlen` which jumps to a construct which looks like this in radare2:

```
┌ 128: size_t sym.imp.strlen (const char *s);
│           0x00035b40      172eb600       auipc t3, 0xb62
│           0x00035b44      033e0e75       ld t3, 1872(t3)
│           0x00035b48      67030e00       jalr t1, t3
│           0x00035b4c      13000000       nop
│           ;-- dlclose:
│           0x00035b50      172eb600       auipc t3, 0xb62
│           0x00035b54      033e8e74       ld t3, 1864(t3)
│           0x00035b58      67030e00       jalr t1, t3
│           0x00035b5c      13000000       nop
│           ;-- erff:
│           0x00035b60      172eb600       auipc t3, 0xb62
│           0x00035b64      033e0e74       ld t3, 1856(t3)
│           0x00035b68      67030e00       jalr t1, t3
│           0x00035b6c      13000000       nop
│           ;-- truncf:
│           0x00035b70      172eb600       auipc t3, 0xb62
│           0x00035b74      033e8e73       ld t3, 1848(t3)
│           0x00035b78      67030e00       jalr t1, t3
│           0x00035b7c      13000000       nop
│           ;-- strncpy:
│           0x00035b80      172eb600       auipc t3, 0xb62
│           0x00035b84      033e0e73       ld t3, 1840(t3)
│           0x00035b88      67030e00       jalr t1, t3
│           0x00035b8c      13000000       nop
│           ;-- write:
│           0x00035b90      172eb600       auipc t3, 0xb62
│           0x00035b94      033e8e72       ld t3, 1832(t3)
│           0x00035b98      67030e00       jalr t1, t3
│           0x00035b9c      13000000       nop
│           ;-- fesetround:
│           0x00035ba0      172eb600       auipc t3, 0xb62
│           0x00035ba4      033e0e72       ld t3, 1824(t3)
│           0x00035ba8      67030e00       jalr t1, t3
│           0x00035bac      13000000       nop
│           ;-- sincos:
│           0x00035bb0      172eb600       auipc t3, 0xb62
│           0x00035bb4      033e8e71       ld t3, 1816(t3)
│           0x00035bb8      67030e00       jalr t1, t3
└           0x00035bbc      13000000       nop
```

Is this a jump table?

It seems strange to me to jump to the strlen function so indirectly. It jumps first to this table, then uses `auipc` (so the address of the table entry plus `0xb62 << 12`) to calculate an address to load. Loads the address + some offset (I assume this is the entry point of `strlen`) and then jumps there. Why not just have a symbol for jumping directly to `strlen`'s entry point?

One possible justification I can think of is code compression - it may be more compact to do this rather than loading/jumping to a symbol at every place `strlen` is called. I also have a feeling it could be something to do with linking?

Comment: It looks like the PLT for the shared library.

Comment: I don't know why it bothers to capture a return address in `t1`?

Comment: @ErikEidt: Probably with lazy dynamic linking, the PLT resolver can use `t1` to identify which `.got.plt` PLT entry to resolve.  On x86-64 for example, PLT stubs push a unique index in the fallback where the initial jump isn't to the library.  These entries don't do that.  Neat hack that takes good advantage of RISC-V's flexible `jalr` instruction, instead of running a separate `ori t1, zero, 3` before a jump.

Comment: Thanks all. Can anyone recommend any good resources for learning concepts such as these? Is there a goto textbook?  I'm sure there are a lot of other concepts that I dont know about